# Convergence Range of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$

By the ratio test we need $\lim_{n \to \infty} | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| < 1 \rightarrow\lim_{n \to \infty} x^2 < 1$. Hence we get the range $-1 < x < 1$.
My question is if we sub $x = -1$ we get the following series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$

**EDIT NOTE:** My mistake here is not realizing that $(-1)^{2n-1} = -1$, and not an alternating series.

By the alternating series test we get $(1) \ b_n > b_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n-1} =0$, so wouldn't we also have to  allow $-1 \leq x < 1$?

Comment: Note that we are using "ratio test" and not "[limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) " which is a different test only valid for series with positive terms.

Comment: The ratio test is inconclusive when the limit is one.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the range $-1 < x < 1$?

Comment: For real $x$, the series converges iff $\lvert x\rvert < 1$. It converges for all complex $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert = 1$ except for $z = \pm 1$ by the complex form of Dirichlet's test.

Comment: You cannot use the alternating series test because it is not an alternating series.

Comment: Ya I am realizing now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2n-1}}{2n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{2n-1}$ is harmonic and diverges therefore the convergence range is $-1 < x < 1$.

Comment: That would make the range $-1 < x < 1$...?

Comment: @A.RadekMartinez Yes of course! Sorry for the confusion.